# PHP Get Basename of File Where Function Called

Tags: php, dirname

Anyone can help me get the basename of directory where the function called? I mean:

file /root/system/file_class.php

```
function find_file($dir, $file) {
    $all_file = scandir($dir);
    ....
}

function does_exist($file) {
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($file);
    $find = find_file($pathinfo["dirname"], $pathinfo["basename"]);
    return $find;
}
```

file /root/app/test.php

```
$is_exist = does_exist("config.php");
```

Under /root/app i have file "config.php, system.php". Do you know how to get the directory where `does_exist()` called? In function `find_file()` argument `$dir` is important, since `scandir()` function need directory path to scaned. I mean, when i want to check file `config.php` i doesn't need to write `/root/app/config.php`. If i not provide fullpath in `$file` argument, the $pathinfo["dirname"] will be `"."`. I've try to use `dirname(__file__)` in `file_find()` function but it's return the directory `/root/system` not `/root/app` where it is the directory of `does_exist()` function called.

I need create those function since i can't use `file_exists()` function.

**Found Solutions**:

I'm using `debug_backtrace()` to get the recent file and line number of where users calling function. For example:

```
function read_text($file = "") {
    if (!$file) {
        $last_debug = next(debug_backtrace());
        echo "Unable to call 'read_text()' in ".$last_debug['file']." at line ".$last_debug['line'].".";
    }
}
```

/home/index.php

`16  $text = read_text();`

The sample output: `Unable to call 'read_text()' in /home/index.php at line 16.`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use any of PHP magic constants

```
__DIR__
__FILE__
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Or use realpath("./");

To define your own constant paths:

define("MYPATH", realpath("./") . "/dir/dir/";

You can then call this MYPATH from everywhere this code (file) is included.